# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client nunjucks/express

Tags: javascript, node.js, nunjucks

I am running the front-end separately from the node server, everytime I update the firebase database, the node client app crash with this error:

> _http_outgoing.js:470
>
> Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent
>   to the client

My code is a very basic api call

```
app.get("/:user/", cors(), (request, response, next) => {
  var user = request.params['user'];
  console.log(user);
  firebase.database().ref(`/master/${user}/`)
  .on('value', snapshot => {
      var obj = snapshot.val()
      var data = []
      var keys = []
      for (let a in obj) {
        data.push(obj[a])
        keys.push(a)
      }
      response.render('index.html', { data });
    });
})
```

Comment: Does `on` don't get called multiple times? `response.render` closes the request as far as I know, so on the next `value` event the response is already closed.

Comment: can you also post the `cord()` middleware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.once` instead of `.on`, to get the current state of the snapshot, instead of retrieving every update. [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write)

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm! I always ignore the database logic and keep blaming node and other libraries ;)